# Shall we 'accept' answers in the private beta?

Tags: discussion

I've had some great answers to my questions so far - thanks all!

Should we 'accept' answers in the private beta? I definitely feel we should upvote as much as possible, but I wonder if leaving answers unaccepted (to encourage people who join us in the public beta to contribute answers) would be better.

Answer (score 3):

Whether to accept an answer or not is entirely your personal decision and it has nothing to do with encouraging people to contribute answers. Even if an answer is accepted, a new user can write an additional answer.

If you think that a new answer is more helpful than the previously accepted one, you can change the acceptance by clicking on the acceptance tick of a new answer.

But, please make sure you accept an answer that solves your problem with the right reference and examples. If there is not a helpful answer, you don't have to accept any answer.

Related question on Meta Stack Exchange:

[How long should/can I wait before accepting an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136314/how-long-should-can-i-wait-before-accepting-an-answer)

[How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)